# Adding controls in background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create some controls after the user logged in.

I have a TabControl with 3 tabs: the first one to login, the second one is a place that needs to show lots of tiles (MahApps.Metro Tile). Each tile represent a hotel room.

And the third tab displays an indeterminate progress bar. When the user logs in, this tab is displayed.

How I did this:

```
    //User is logged in, so display the progress bar and add controls
    tabControl.SelectedIndex = 2; // display the progress bar tab

    private void populateHotel(Hotel hotel)
    {
        List<Room> rooms = hotel.rooms;
        Tile tile;
        tile_wrapper.Children.Clear();
        foreach (Room room in rooms)
        {
            sql.insertHotelRoom(room);
            tile = new Tile();
            tile.Title = room.room_num;
            tile.Content = room.name_fa;              
            tile.FontFamily = titleRooms.FontFamily; // titleRooms is a textbox
            tile.TitleFontSize = item1.TitleFontSize; // item1 is an already created tile
            tile.FontSize = item1.FontSize;
            tile_wrapper.Children.Add(tile);

        }
        // Now display the rooms tab
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

The problem is, this freezes the UI thread and everything freezes, including the progress bar until it creates all the tiles.

How can I do the add controls so the progress bar still responds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is to mix the business code that inserts the `Hotel` with the UI code that displays it. It's not a good idea to mix business code and UI code. Along with the maintainability issues this creates, it is contributing to your problem, because the UI has to wait for your `insertHotelRoom` operations and can't react to user input.

The first thing you should do is to separate your concerns:

```
private List<Room> insertHotelRooms(Hotel hotel)
{
    List<Room> rooms = hotel.rooms;
    foreach (Room room in rooms)
    {
        sql.insertHotelRoom(room);
        rooms.Add(room);
    }
    return rooms;
}


private void populateHotelTab(List<Room> rooms)
{
    Tile tile;
    tile_wrapper.Children.Clear();
    foreach (Room room in rooms)
    {
        tile = new Tile();
        tile.Title = room.room_num;
        tile.Content = room.name_fa;              
        tile.FontFamily = titleRooms.FontFamily; // titleRooms is a textbox
        tile.TitleFontSize = item1.TitleFontSize; // item1 is an already created tile
        tile.FontSize = item1.FontSize;
        tile_wrapper.Children.Add(tile);

    }
    // Now display the rooms tab
    tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

You can now run the operation in a task and dispatch the UI operation back to the UI thread:

```
Task insertRoomsTask = Task.Run( () => {
    List<Room> rooms = insertRooms(hotel);
    tile_wrapper.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => populateHotelTab(rooms));
});
```

Comment: As a test, if I add a Thread.Sleep(1000) in the foreach loop in populateHotelTab, should the UI still respond? I did this, but the progress bar still freezes.

Comment: @SMahdiS: In which `foreach` loop? If you add the `Thread.Sleep` in `populateHotelTab`, then the UI would still freeze. That is the expected behaviour if you freeze the UI thread. But why would you do that? The whole point of the solution is to do the time-consuming stuff outside the UI thread. And using `Thread.Sleep` in a task is not recommended, because you don't know which scheduler you're running on.

Comment: I learned a lot, thank you. By the way what is with that thing: "() => {}". Is that a delegate? If not, what is it and what should I google for? I get used to Java  programming and these things seems new to me.

Comment: @SMahdiS: That is a lambda expression, which is equivalent to a delegate.

Comment: It still has some delays and freezes a bit. I think it is due to: tile_wrapper.Children.Add(tile); Is it inevitable?

Answer (score 0):

```
//User is logged in, so display the progress bar and add controls
tabControl.SelectedIndex = 2; // display the progress bar tab

private void populateHotel(Hotel hotel)
{
    List<Room> rooms = hotel.rooms;
    Tile tile;
    tile_wrapper.Children.Clear();

    // Use a count variable to keep track of how many rooms have been processed
    int count = 0;

    foreach (Room room in rooms)
    {
        // Update the value of the progress bar
        progressbar1.Value = count++ * 100 / rooms.Count;
        // Cause the progress bar to refresh
        progressbar1.Refresh();

        sql.insertHotelRoom(room);
        tile = new Tile();
        tile.Title = room.room_num;
        tile.Content = room.name_fa;              
        tile.FontFamily = titleRooms.FontFamily; // titleRooms is a textbox
        tile.TitleFontSize = item1.TitleFontSize; // item1 is an already created tile
        tile.FontSize = item1.FontSize;
        tile_wrapper.Children.Add(tile);

    }
    // Now display the rooms tab
    tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the progress bar is an indeterminate MetroProgressBar and does not have a Refresh() method. Although it has an UpdateLayout() but that didn't work too.

Comment: Having UI logic in a function called populateHotel() isn't ideal.

You could use a Background worker to do the SQL insert (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) but first I would try to convert your app to use async calls. It's very likely that you don't need to manually muck around with threads and can rely on an async callback to provide enough time for the main UI thread to keep everything responsive.

Comment: No, it's not. It would be better I suppose to create a delegate that is called when each room is updated that the 3rd tab could assign to. Then you could run the populateHotel() on a different thread from the UI.

Comment: Check out this link:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/